# Как в PWA приложении Angular запретить кеширование api?

Tags: angular, pwa, service-worker

Как в PWA приложении Angular запретить кеширование api ?

Не работает настройка в ngsw-config.json

Мне нужно все запросы кешировать, а api , имеющее ссылку ** /api/ ** - нет

Как это реализовать?